# Error when fetch timing using sitespeed.io and firefox

Tags: 14.04, server, firefox, websites, graphite

I´m working with sitespeed.io to know the performance of my websites.
I run this command for example `$ sitespeed.io -u http://sitespeed.io -b firefox`
the collecting metric is going well, but i face a problem when i want to fetch timing
here is the Error

```
Fetching http://sitespeed.io (1 of 3)
[Error: Timed out waiting for the WebDriver server at http://127.0.0.1/XXX]
```

ist it a problem between Selenium webdriver and firefox?
this is the version of my Mozilla Firefox 41.0.2
for the selenium webdriver 2.46.1

when i see this file i´m not sure if firefox is supported with the selenium that i use http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/java/CHANGELOG

Could SO told me where is the problem. I have trying many times but in vain.
THX

Comment: This change looks problematic: Native events in Firefox relied on an API that Mozilla no longer provides. As such, fall back to synthesized events on recent Firefox  versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i Found this cammand that help me to fetch timing :
`$xvfb-run sitespeed.io -u http://www.sitespeed.io -b firefox`